# How to highlight a searched text inside a document which is indexed in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Apache Solr 8.6 to index the documents using POST Tool in Linux as mentioned in the [Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/about-this-guide.html).

**POST Tool Command**

```
bin/post -c testcore /testdocs/
```

The documents are getting indexed successfully. Now when I searched the string eg: **hello** in Solr Admin UI, It is returning the matching documents.

Now I want to highlight this string **"hello"** which is present inside the document as content. But I am unable to achieve the same.
I have tried putting highlighting enabled and entering text_* in the hl.fl=text_*. Yet I am unable to achieve the result. However if this searched string is present in any of the indexed fields it is correctly highlighting in the results.

In **managed-schema.xml** i have added content and text Fields as shown below.

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/> 

<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

**I have tried below queries:**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?q=_text_%3a*hello*&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.usephrasehighlighter=true

http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?q=_text_%3a*hello*&hl=true&hl.fl=text_*&hl.usephrasehighlighter=true
```

Will be grateful if you could guide me further.

**Edit: As per recommendation**

I have changed the fields of content and text as shown below, but it is not working either. That means when I am searching the text string it is not highlighting the searched string inside the document as content.

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/> 
    
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: So highlighting works with `hl.fl=text_*` but not with `hl.fl=content` (that's not very clear) ? How are these fields defined (field+fieldType) ?

Comment: No both queries are not working..i tried both ways. I have defined content and text Fields in managed schema.xml as 

   <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

Comment: Ok, please edit your question to make it clear for every one (it's not readable in the comments).

Comment: I have updated the managed-schema.xml fields snippet in the question

Comment: Ok, you need to set both `indexed="true"` and `stored="true"` for highlighting to work on your fields, that's the deal.

Comment: Thanks for guidance.I will update the same and let you know the results

Comment: @EricLavault I have tried it out.But the searched text inside the document as content is not highlighting

Comment: You need to reindex.

Comment: I have tried but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the issue resolved by modifying **_text _** field in **manage-schema.xml** file. I have changed the value of **stored="false" to stored="true"** as shown in below syntax.

```
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Then I have restarted the solr and refindexed the document.

Now i have fired the query to highlight the text as shown below. In this query i have used **hl=on & hl.fl=_text _** to highlight the comment.

**Query to highlight the searched string**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?q=_text_%3a*hello*&hl=on&hl.fl=_text_
```